# Can I omit certain lines from the Feed The Beast console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forge

Whenever somebody logs into my server, I see all of these lines that I have no use for. I know what they are for, but I don't need them clogging up console space. Is there any way I can remove this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like log4j, maybe you can set the logging level to Error?

Comment: @Lyrion You could add that as an answer, and perhaps add some details.

Comment: I'll need to go check the feed the beast sources before i know it is right tho. Give me some time if I can find it i will let you know, if i can't i will let you know aswell.

Comment: What OS? *nixes have some native tools and filesystem features (`screen`, `grep`, and named pipes) that could be used together to filter the output.

Comment: Are you not launching the graphical server window too? Its output is much less cluttered because it doesn't line-wrap those long lists of mods.

Comment: I use `nogui` because I find it cleaner when using vanilla. Apparently, this is not the case with FTB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding information in the console, you could use the graphical one provided to you (minecraft_server.jar), which, as @SevenSidedDie said, removes all the clutter because it doesn't wrap lines. However, if like me, you use perimeters in a .bat file to launch it, you would want to use a file called [invisible.vbs](https://superuser.com/a/62646/140967) to hide the black console. It doesn't hide the graphical one because the graphical one is launched from the console.

Comment: I'm still interested to know if there's a solution to the original question. Hosted servers can surface their logs through web clients, which automatically wrap these lines. If I just want to take a quick glance at the log, I'm assaulted with the blocks of installed mods.